# Adding custom webhook configuration in alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have a custom webhook URL and I need to configure the same in alertmanager for getting alert notification. But my configuration is not working as expected. getting following error in alertmanager,

`level=error ts=2019-04-22T09:31:46.038681545Z caller=dispatch.go:279 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="cancelling notify retry for \"webhook\" due to unrecoverable error: unexpected status code 404 from http://example.com:9898/TrigerToSlack"`

My Alertmanager configuration is as follows,

`````
route:

  group_by: ['job']

  group_wait: 1s

  group_interval: 5m

  repeat_interval: 12h

  receiver: webhook

  routes:
  - receiver: webhook
    continue: true  
receivers:
    - name: webhook
      webhook_configs:
      - url: 'webhook URL'
        send_resolved: true````
`````

Comment: Your error message says `http://example.com:9898/TrigerToSlack` - triger with just one `g`, is that a typo?

Comment: No, it is not.  webhook url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. My API call was a POST but i have defined it as a GET. Changed the GET to POST and everything works fine after that.

Comment: where did you actually change it? was there such attribute to webhook_config?